# trying to draw dotted lines over the chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Hey Guys I'm trying to draw dotted lines over my highcharts chart but when I try this the lines either push the chart out of position or skip over the chart and continue past it.I'm also trying to put labels on the top of each barchart too

here's my code

```
$(function () {
        $('#container5').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'

            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: { enabled: false },
            exporting: {
                   enabled:false
                },

             credits: {
                  enabled: false
              },

              legend: {
                  enabled:false
              },
            xAxis: {
                 labels:
                    {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    lineColor: 'transparent',
                     minorTickLength: 0,
                       tickLength: 0,
                       min: 0,
                          lineWidth: 0,
                   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                   lineColor: 'transparent',

                      gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                categories: ['']
            },
            yAxis: {
                 labels:
                    {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    lineColor: 'transparent',
                     minorTickLength: 0,
                       tickLength: 0,
                       min: 0,
                          lineWidth: 0,
                   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                   lineColor: 'transparent',


                      gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ' '
                },

            },


            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                     animation: false

                },
                series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: '10',
                data: [10],
                 pointWidth: 50,
                 groupPadding: 0,
                 color: '#f7a35c'
            }, {
                name: '12',
                data: [12],
                pointWidth: 50,
                groupPadding: 0,
                color: '#004A98'
            }, {
                name: '12',
                data: [12],
                pointWidth: 50,
                groupPadding: 0,
                color: '#509ADC'
            }]
        });
    });
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-2" id="container5" style="width: 200px; height: 700px; margin:auto"></div>
```

It looks like

[Picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2AyS.png)

but I want it to look like this

[Picture two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ySu.png)

Answer (score 2):

Deffine your plot lines on YAxis like this. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines/)

```
yAxis: {
     title: {
         ...
     },
     plotLines: [{
         value: minValue,
         color: 'green',
         dashStyle: 'shortdash',
         width: 2,
         label: {
             text: 'Last quarter minimum'
         }
     }, {
         value: maxValue,
         color: 'red',
         dashStyle: 'shortdash',
         width: 2,
         label: {
             text: 'Last quarter maximum'
         }
     }]
 }
```

**EDIT**

In addition to, if you want to align the plotLines to the left you can try this:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x*2,y + height,'L',0,y + width];
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m85yv3aq/9/)

Comment: is there anyway I can align these plotLines to the left?

Comment: I've tried it and It's very hard, but you can check all that i could do because maybe it can helps you. http://jsfiddle.net/m85yv3aq/9/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to add custom line in the chart.

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 100])
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();
```

Comment: do you have any jsFiddle examples of this?

Comment: In the docs, you have a live demo of renderer using. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-path/